# How can i write the text show in red rectangle?

Tags: environments

[image]

How can i write the text show in red rectangle?

Comment: Do you require also the red rectangle?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lp{3.5in}} %% change the number to required number
\textbf{Objectives:} & \textit{Finding optimal weights} $\omega^*$ to:\par
 \textbf{Maximize:} $PICP(\omega)$;\par
\textbf{Minimize:} $PIN\ AW(\omega)$.\\
\textbf{Constraints:} & $PIN\ AW(\omega)>0;$\par
$\mu\le PICP(\omega)\le 1$.
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]